# Is it Possible to show <a> element text inside <div> with display none?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to show the text from 'a' element which is inside a 'div' with display none?

I tried something like this.

```
.tabTwo{
        position: relative;             
        margin-left: 190px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        display: none;
            a{
                display: inline;
            }
}
```

**Update With Solution** Thanks to first answer I could solve my own problem which was to use visibility instead of display.

```
.tabTwo
        position: relative;             
        margin-left: 190px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        visibility: hidden;
            a{
                 visibility: visible;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. display:none means "this element, and all of its child elements, should not be displayed".

Comment: Thank you, this led me to the answear. Wich was to use visiblity: hidden and visibility: visible on 'a' tag